# How can I get my WinForm back after it claims a class is named "?"?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

I selected a control on my form and hit the Delete key. It wouldn't delete. I then selected another control, right-clicked, and selected Properties. The Properties pane displayed, but blank. I then got:

[image]

If I gave a class the name "?", it certainly was not intentional. How can I unmangle this mangled mess?

### UPDATE

The compiler is completely confused, because it tells me, "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" on this line of code:

```
else if (cmbxSel.Equals("CHECKBOX"))
```

...and this is just one of 39 errors that all-of-a-sudden "popped up."

### UPDATE 2

There is nothing weird looking, AFAICT, in the Designer.cs file. It is just stuff like:

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

/// <summary>
/// Clean up any resources being used.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.ckbxUseScrollViewer = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
    this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
    this.tabPageRow0 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
    this.lblRow0Element5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lblRow0Element4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lblRow0Element3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lblRow0Element2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lblRow0Element1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.lblRow0Element0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.cmbxRow0Element5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
    this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.cmbxRow0Element4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
    . . .
```

...and searching for the purported "?" turns up nothing.

### UPDATE 3

And there are many other "crazy" error messages in the related code/.cs file, such as:

"***Identifier expected***" here:

```
safeText = replaceIllegalCharsWithUnderscore(btnText);
```

..."***Invalid token '!=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration***" here:

```
if (string.Empty != cmbxSel)
```

..."***Method must have a return type***" here:

```
safeText = replaceIllegalCharsWithUnderscore(btnText);
```

..."***Type expected***" here:

```
stringXMLEntry = string.Format("<string name=\"{0}\">{1}</string>\"", btnStringId, btnText);
```

...and "***Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected***" on the "}" line here:

```
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
else if (cmbxSel.Equals("RADIOGROUP"))
```

IOW, it's as if the compiler has a severe case of vertigo/disorientation.

### UPDATE 4

Problem solved; It was all because somehow this:

```
// and, even before that (if ckbxUseScrollViewer is checked), add the <ScrollView>      
private string getXMLForElement(ComboBox cmbxCtrl, Label lblCtrl)
```

...had become this:

```
// and, even before that (if ckbxUseScrollViewer is checked), add the <ScrollView>      private string getXMLForElement(ComboBox cmbxCtrl, Label lblCtrl)
```

Once I inserted a crlf (positioned the cursor (I had been the curser prior to that) before the "private") and mashed the Enter button), all was well again. I went from 39 errors and 504 warnings (yes, 504) to 0 and 0.

How that happened when selecting a control in the designer and masching the Delete key, I'll probably never understand, but that must have been what happened...

How I found the source (no pun intended) of the problem was by looking at the first of those warnings:

```
CSharp.CsParser : A syntax error has been discovered in file C:\DroidLayoutBuilder\DroidLayoutBuilder\Form1.cs on line 389.
```

...which took me right to that spot.

Isn't it bizarre that such a thing would cause that many errors and warnings, and for the designer to complain so bitterly?!?

### UPDATE 5

Oddly enough, I got the err msg in the designer again, but the project runs fine. Perhaps related (???) is I keep getting, in the code-behind file, "You have mixed tabs and spaces. Fix this?" The first couple of times, I selected "Tabify" not knowing how the code got untabbified, but I finally grew tired of the nagging, and selected "Don't show again" - yet, the implied promise to quit the nagging was a bald (or is it bold)-faced lie.

Comment: Do you have good source control?

Comment: I'd start by opening the Designer.cs file and looking for botched code there.  If you're lucky, the IDE will highlight them.

Comment: Look at the <form>.designer.cs (don't change anything if you don't have a backup), compare it with a working one. Probably the problem will be clear

Comment: Nothing weird? Where is the namespace declaration?

Comment: @Steve: I didn't copy it. I was only showing the more interesting parts. I also didn't show the "partial class" bit.

Comment: However should be something wrong in the designer.cs. If you are willing to share it and the form.cs I could  take a look at it as a whole (pastebin.com)

Comment: @Steve: Okay, thanks; here it is: http://pastebin.com/8bM6Aj3K

Comment: I have managed to open the form in vs 2013. I have copied your text in a new file and saved it with a form.designer.cs name, then I removed all the event handlers (I don't have that code) and manually created a new form.cs file. At this point I have added the form.cs to a VS project and it loaded the form. I suggest to do something like this. Save your file in another location and remove them from your project. Then try to build the new files and add to your project. Then readd pieces of the original Form.cs and look if the designer still works.

Comment: Why the down vote on this question?  It seems legit to me.

Comment: @Brandon: Because he hate me (I assume it was a he, because females are sugar and spice and everything nice, and would never do such a thing).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - Well, I up voted to counter balance it.  And I still stand by what I posted about the validity of the question.

Comment: @Brandon: Yeah, I think it's at least interesting to see how what would seem a common problem ended up leading me in such odd directions.